# Symfony 5 : Could not find configuration for a filter in liip / LiipImagineBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony5, vichuploaderbundle, liipimaginebundle

I want to user `liip/LiipImagineBundle` for `vich/uploader-bundle` as per documents. I installed packages and configured them in Symfony 5.

But showing error: **Could not find configuration for a filter**

Here is my `composer.json`:

```
    ...
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.*",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.15"
    ...
```

Config file: `config/packages/liip_imagine.yaml`

```
liip_imagine:
    # valid drivers options include "gd" or "gmagick" or "imagick"
    driver: gd
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/products'
                cache_prefix: imagine/cache
    filter_sets:
        filters:
            cache: ~
        avatar:
            quality: 75
            cache: ~
            filters:
                thumbnail:
                    size:
                        - 120
                        - 120
                    mode: outbound
            post_processors: {  }
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                locator: filesystem
                data_root:
                    - '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/products'
                allow_unresolvable_data_roots: false
                bundle_resources:
                    enabled: false
                    access_control_type: blacklist
                    access_control_list: {  }
    cache: default
    cache_base_path: ''
    data_loader: default
    default_image: null
    default_filter_set_settings:
        quality: 100
        jpeg_quality: null
        png_compression_level: null
        png_compression_filter: null
        format: null
        animated: false
        cache: null
        data_loader: null
        default_image: null
        filters: {  }
        post_processors: {  }
    controller:
        filter_action: 'Liip\ImagineBundle\Controller\ImagineController::filterAction'
        filter_runtime_action: 'Liip\ImagineBundle\Controller\ImagineController::filterRuntimeAction'
        redirect_response_code: 301
    enqueue: false
    templating: true
```

and route file :  `config/routes/liip_imagine.yaml`

```
_liip_imagine:
resource:
    "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"
```

ERROR: "Could not find configuration for a filter"

how do I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I am working with liip_imagine on a symfony 5.3 project and I found that my configuration in yaml is slighty different. I hope this can help you.

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
    default:
        web_path:
            web_root: "%kernel.project_dir%/public"
            cache_prefix: "images/cache"
loaders:
    default:
        filesystem:
            data_root: "uploads/images/"
            bundle_resources:
                enabled: true
driver:  "gd"
data_loader:  default
default_image: null
controller:
    filter_action: liip_imagine.controller:filterAction
    filter_runtime_action: liip_imagine.controller:filterRuntimeActio
filter_sets:
```

I created the folders manually in my case. The file in twig should be something like {{ asset(imagename.jpg) }} as the yaml will resolve the path for you.

I hope it helps you

regards.

Comment: As `imagine/imagine` is listed in the `require` section of that package, it's pretty unlikely that the OP installed `liip/imagine-bundle` without installing imagine itself